# import image from path provided in an object

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6

This is in a React-Native application:

I have an object nesting in a docs object. Something like:

```
const docs = {
  general: {
    g1:{
      title: 'Bradycardia',
      image: '../assets/pg001_main.png',
    },
    ...
    g56: {
      title: 'Chest Tube Management',
      image: '../assets/pg056_main.png',
    },
  },
  detailed: {
    d57: {
      title: 'Cardiac Arrest',
      image: '../assets/pg057_main.png',
    },
    ...
    d136: {
      title: 'blah',
      image: '../assets/pg136_main.png',
    },
  },
};
```

and I cannot figure out how to use that string to get an image showing in React-Native.

I have tried:

```
const algo = require(docs.general.image);

<Image source={ algo } />
<Image source={require(docs.general.image)} />
```

as well as

```
const algoStr = docs.general.image;
const algo = require(algoStr);
```

Comment: I made an edit very early on to clarify that this was for ReactNative, and not React.

Answer (score 0):

How about requiring the image, sticking it in a variable and attaching that variable to the `image` property. Like so,

`const image = require('../assets/pg001_main.png');
 const docs = {
  general: {
    title: 'Bradycardia',
    image,
  }
};`

Comment: I'd have to import 136 images manually, and I was trying to shorten work by just having a component do the work for me, but if that doesn't work, then I guess I'm SOL.

Comment: ooh my bad. Thought it was for a little amount

Comment: Haha, no worries. If it were a little side project with 6 or 7 images, no doubt this'd work great.